# Check for null before setting the variable - without if-else

Tags: java, java-8, lombok

I use `Lombok-Builder` to build my `api` java object from an `entity` object

```
RewardApi.builder()
                .rewardId(rewardEntity.getrewardId())
                .rewardTitle(rewardEntity.getrewardTitle())
                .rewardText(rewardEntity.getrewardText())
                .rewardFor(rewardEntity.getrewardFor())
                .rewardType(rewardEntity.getrewardType())
                .rewardFromDate(rewardEntity.getrewardFromDate().toZonedDateTime())
                .rewardToDate(rewardEntity.getrewardToDate().toZonedDateTime())
                .isDisplayOn(rewardEntity.getIsDisplayOn())
                .createdId(rewardEntity.getCreatedId())
                .updatedId(rewardEntity.getUpdatedId())
                .createdDate(rewardEntity.getCreatedDate().toZonedDateTime())
                .lastModifiedDate(rewardEntity.getLastModifiedDate().toZonedDateTime())
                .build();
```

I am getting `nullPointerException` while am setting `lastModifiedDate` field because the `entity` object is getting that field as `null` and am executing `toZonedDateTime()` on top of `null`

How to tackle this without the traditional way (as mentioned below) of doing

`if (null!=rewardEntity.getLastModifiedDate(){....}`

I wanted to check `null` while i set the variable using the `builder-pattern` and not do a `null` check after building the object. Any ways ?

Comment: use a ternary operator

Comment: `rewardEntity.getLastModifiedDate() != null? rewardEntity.getLastModifiedDate().toZonedDateTime() : null` I guess

Comment: Do you have flexibility of using java 8, if yes then I'd suggest to wrap it in optional somewhat like ```Optional.ofNullable(rewardEntity.getLastModifiedDate()).map(z->z.toZonedDateTime()).orElse(null);```

Comment: @foxt7ot I'd say yes, given the tags.

Comment: @AndyTurner Huh!! Totally missed that :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the kids like `Optional` these days:

```
Optional.ofNullable(rewardEntity.getLastModifiedDate())
    .map(r -> r.toZonedDateTime())
    .orElse(null) // or some other default value
```

Comment: and `OffsetDateTime::toZonedDateTime` instead of `r -> r.toZonedDateTime()`, but I don't get why people are pushing so much these solutions with `Optional`

Comment: @Adrian provided `getLastModifiedDate()` returns a (subclass of) `OffsetDateTime`, yes.

Comment: This is pretty cool, i had this piece of code in a method and called it in the place where am setting the `lastModifiedDate`

Answer (score 4):

```
rewardEntity.getLastModifiedDate() != null ? rewardEntity.getLastModifiedDate().toZonedDateTime() : null
```

It is called the conditional operator, which is a ternary operator because it has three operands.

Comment: sorry I was typing from my phone

Comment: I would not recommend saving a null value , might face NPE later

Comment: but the OP was most probably already doing that - how do you think that Builder works?

Answer (score 1):

you can have a generic utility method that handles null cases like

```
static <T, R> R transform(T obj, Function<T, R> function) {
    return obj != null ? function.apply(obj) : null;
}
```

and use it as follows

```
.rewardToDate(transform(rewardEntity.getRewardToDate(), OffsetDateTime::toZonedDateTime))
```

Actually better is to "override" lombok builder methods, because what you have now seems more like a placeholder/DTO and not builder:

```
@Builder
private static class RewardApi {
    //...
    private ZonedDateTime rewardToDate;

    public static class RewardApiBuilder {

        public RewardApiBuilder rewardToDate(OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime) {
            if(offsetDateTime != null) {
                this.rewardToDate = offsetDateTime.toZonedDateTime();
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```